# Generated classes by JAXB conflicting with each other

Tags: xml, jaxb, jaxb2, xjc

I generated **multiple classes from multiple XML files** using **JAXB xjc** tool.

These XML files have **common tag names**, which involves that, when I generated the java classes I had **multiple classes with the same name**. I've put them into different packages and renamed them consequently.

But I still have this error:

> The element name {}Document has more than one mapping.    this problem
>   is related to the following location:         at public
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
>   com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.bal.ObjectFactory.createDocument(com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.bal.DocumentTypeBal)
>         at com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.bal.ObjectFactory    this problem is
>   related to the following location:        at public
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
>   com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.addr.ObjectFactory.createDocument(com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.addr.DocumentTypeAddr)
>         at com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.addr.ObjectFactory

...Repeated many times in the console.

---

**EDIT**

When I first faced the conflict problem I renamed the conflicting classes, so for example:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "DocumentType", propOrder = { "addressPage" })
public class DocumentType {
```

Had been changed for:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "DocumentTypeAddr", propOrder = { "addressPage" })
public class DocumentTypeAddr {
```

---

**I regenarated the classes, they are know without any manual change. Here is the error that I have:**

Two classes have the same XML type name "DocumentType". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.addr.DocumentType
        at public com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.addr.DocumentType com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.addr.ObjectFactory.createDocumentType()
        at com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.addr.ObjectFactory
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.bal.DocumentType
        at public com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.bal.DocumentType com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.bal.ObjectFactory.createDocumentType()
        at com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.bal.ObjectFactory
The element name {}Document has more than one mapping.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.bal.ObjectFactory.createDocument(com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.bal.DocumentType)
        at com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.bal.ObjectFactory
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.addr.ObjectFactory.createDocument(com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.addr.DocumentType)
        at com.xxx.generatedByJaxb.addr.ObjectFactory

**Here is an example of a xsd file (between the 7 xsd files that I generate the classes from):**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="Document" type="DocumentType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="DateType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Type"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="Date"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="HH"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="MM"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="SS"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ChargeType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="Id" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="Amount" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="CurrCode" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="Type" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="PT" use="optional"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="BalancePageType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="DateType" name="Date"/>
      <xs:element type="ChargeType" name="Charge" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="DocumentType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="BalancePageType" name="BalancePage"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Sender"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Id"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="BAId"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Please post an example of your schemas and conflicting classes.

Comment: There is many classes in conflict

Comment: And the XML files are confidential sorry

Comment: I've tried to define a diffrent namespace for each class but it doesn't work

Comment: Do you have a `targetNamespace` attribute in your schemas?

Comment: @lexicore No I haven't. Shall I add it?

Comment: If you control these schemas thet I will defnitely advise you to do so. Otherwise you're doing the chameleon design which is very bad for JAXB. See http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/ch10_10.htm and http://www.kohsuke.org/xmlschema/XMLSchemaDOsAndDONTs.html#avoid_chameleon

Comment: I know this is old, but [the solution I posted in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71072922/2516673) might be of help for someone.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full answer (which is not possible under the given conditions), but it aims to provide first pointers.

It is hard to help you if you can't show any of your code. If your original stuff is confidential, try to make an anonymized samples.

So here's some very general advice:

- Your goal is to eliminate duplicate classes.
- Compile your schemas [one namespace per package](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Customizing_Java_packages.html) so that you don't have duplicate classes.
- You may be facing [a chameleon schemas](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/ch10_10.htm). This is a very bad design pattern for JAXB, can't help.
- If you compile your schemas with XJC, do not copy/rename classes manually. Learn [how to use binding files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html).

I guess that the best way to proceed for you would be to put together a small non-confidential example, which is still demonstrative and relevant to your use case.

Comment: I already manually renamed some classes: see my edit. Can it cause the problem? Shall all undo all the rename actions ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide advice without knowing the whole picture. Generally renaming or modifying generated code in any way is not a good idea since your changes will void on the next generation. But this is NOT an advice to revert anything.